# Alias for multiple parameters in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have some sort of code that goes something like this:

```
export async function execute(conf: Record<string, string>, path: string, params: Array<string>) {

    const cmd = params[1];
    const commandOption = params.slice(2)
    switch(cmd){
        case "param_1":
            return await function1(path, conf, commandOption)
            break;
        case "param_2":
            return await function2(path, conf, commandOption)
            break;
        case "param_3":
            return await function3(path, conf, commandOption)
            break;
        default:
            console.log("command not entered")
            break;
    }

}


async function function1(path: string, conf: Record<string, string>, params: Array<string>) {
    ...
}
async function function2(path: string, conf: Record<string, string>, params: Array<string>) {
    ...
}

..
```

The parameters are defined somewhere else in the script with value from user input when running the script. The functions are similar so they have the same parameters.

I was wondering if I can make this more DRY and simple by making an alias that holds all 3 parameters.

Something like this:

```
alias allParameters = (path, conf, commandOption)

or even

alias allParametersFunc = (conf: Record<string, string>, path: string, params: Array<string>)

export async function execute(allParametersFunc) {

    const cmd = params[1];
    const commandOption = params.slice(2)
    switch(cmd){
        case "param_1":
            return await function1(allParameters)
            break;
        case "param_2":
            return await function2(allParameters)
            break;
        case "param_3":
            return await function3(allParameters)
            break;
        default:
            console.log("command not entered")
            break;
    }

}


async function function1(allParametersFunc) {
    ...
}
async function function2(allParametersFunc) {
    ...
}

...
```

I figured it's probably doable with objects but this seems more intuitive like yaml anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an interface or a type beforehand that includes the arguments and return value types.

```
type FnType = (conf: Record<string, string>, path: string, params: Array<string>) => Promise<string>;

const fn1: FnType = (conf, path, params) => {
  // ...
  return Promise.resolve('x');
};
const fn2: FnType = (conf, path, params) => {
  // ...
  return Promise.resolve('x');
}
```

If the return values differ, you can make the function type generic instead, and pass in the return type when defining:

```
type FnType<T> = (conf: Record<string, string>, path: string, params: Array<string>) => Promise<T>;

const fn1: FnType<string> = (conf, path, params) => {
  // ...
  return Promise.resolve('x');
};
const fn2: FnType<number> = (conf, path, params) => {
  // ...
  return Promise.resolve(5);
}
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting how you do a vanilla function, as that's what the OP has: `function fn3(...args: Parameters<FnType>): ReturnType<FnType>`

Comment: I don't understand this, and it does not make any less lines or smaller lines so I don't even get the point of this way of doing.

Comment: @ozzyMandiaz You were asking about being able to type multiple parameters for multiple functions with a single type, and this shows you how you can do that - by using a single `FnType`, you don't need to type the types of the function parameters or the return value every time. You only have to do it once. Isn't that what you were looking for?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't like the solution. It just makes it more complicated and makes even more lines.

Comment: @ozzyMandiaz It does what you were asking for and keeps the code as DRY as possible - each parameter is now typed exactly once, and you don't need to type the same ones over again for each function. A similar approach would be to type the parameters inline in one of the functions, then use `typeof` that function to use the same type for the rest. I don't think an even more terse option exists.

Comment: Okay, I guess you explained to me in a way that it cannot be done the way I want it. I don't understand much about TS so I will give you the green checkmark.